# How to make this css take effect in Bootstrap 2.3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-2

Not a bootstrap frequent user nor css expert. I have the following bootstrap 2.3 css but the .pop-c class isn't taking effect. I usually need to add it after bootstrap but this is problematic because we are essentially adding it to the web page. How can I specify in my .css.scss file to have .pop-c take effect (Rails 3.2.18 asset pipeline_?

The css is:

```
<style>
.pop-c{
  margin: 0px !important;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

and the html is

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="span1 pop-c">id</div>
   <div class="span1">is_enabled</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works okay here: http://jsfiddle.net/GLdcs/1/ Are you sure you have the css file included properly?

Comment: @creimers Your fiddle isn't loading bootstrap, 404. Updated, and yes seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/GLdcs/2/